# Python callable argument in **kwargs

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
def aggregate(self, **kwargs):
    for node in self:
        for prop, val in kwargs.values():
            set_val = val(node) if callable(val) else val
            setattr(node, prop, set_val)
    return self
```

When i'm trying to set in `**kwargs` a callable variable, function throw this error:

```
Message: TypeError("'function' object is not iterable",)
```

Please help. Can't understand where the problem is 
Method call are following:
`obj.aggregate(my_key=_test)` where `_test` are callable

Answer (score 7):

You're iterating `.values()`, where each value is a single item, but you're unpacking to *two* names, `prop` and `val`. The error occurs when it effectively tries to assign `prop, val = _test`.

Looks like you meant to iterate `.items()`, not `.values()`. That way, `prop` would be `"my_key"`, and `val` `_test` as expected.

Comment: works like charm, thanks for the answer. I'll be more careful in the future